# Need to change the pointing position of a bootstrap caret

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with a collapsible menu associated with it. When the page loads the menu is collapsed. When you click on the button I would like the caret to change its pointing position so that people know that they can click the button again to close the menu.

I found this solution:
[How to change the bootstrap caret pointing position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870746/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-caret-pointing-position)

The problem with the above solution is that it only changes the caret position once the area is closed, I need it to change once its opened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem I was having. All I had to do was add the class "collapsed" to the button.