# Bootstrap v3 Caret Position toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find the default way that bootstrap toggles the up/down display of the caret when toggling a `.collapse` div.

So the code is:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-8'><h3>Select Image</h3></div>
    <div class='col-sm-4 text-right'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#image-files' aria-expanded="false"><b class="caret"></b></button></div>
</div>
<div id='image-files' class='collapse'>
    <div class='row'>
    Content
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure i've read somewhere that the bootstrap library will *automatically* change the caret from down to up somehow.

Of course I could use a line of Jquery to do it but I'm sure it's built into bootstrap and I want to know how to use that.

Comment: I dont think there's any solution exist using *Bootstrap* default but you can use the attributes of the `button` to achieve what you seek via adding this piece of *CSS* code as: `button[aria-expanded=true] .caret {  border-top: 0;  border-bottom: 4px solid #000; }`

Comment: I found the statement in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-carets: _"Note that the default caret will reverse automatically in dropup menus."_ - But even in their examples it does not... - But you could do it in CSS, because an class like `open` or `collapsed` would be added by bootstrap, e.g. `.open .caret {
    border-bottom: 4px dashed;
    border-top: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in up/down option if this is what you are looking for:

```
<span class="dropup">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</span>
```

(Or are you looking for any more detail or something else? I am not completely sure I understood your problem perfectly.)

Comment: Oh, and also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368802/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-caret-pointing-direction-on-click-event

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870746/how-to-change-the-bootstrap-caret-pointing-position

Comment: aaaand this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760047/upside-down-caret

Comment: OP wants to toggle the up/down view of the caret icon on the click of the `button` respectively.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay yes, I'm sure bootstrap does it itself, without me having to code it.

Comment: Well, then I am almost certain you will have to do some workaround (like the accepted answer in my first commented link)